# How To Style background-image CSS

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to figure how I can style an image that I have loaded with CSS, I did this by using the code:

```
.news1 {
content: url("https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300");
}
```

I then tried to style this by doing:

```
.news1 img:hover {
 -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I then also tried:

```
 .news1 content:hover {
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
```

Comment: it seems as if your image is not defined through the html <img/>-tag but through plain css

Comment: There's no way `content` would work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to set the background image in CSS you should set the image use the `background` property.

```css
.news1 {
  background-image: url("https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  height:300px;
  width: 300px;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.news1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="news1"></div>
```

Comment: I tried using the background property but it changes the height of the image to about 20px but still keeps the width

Comment: @RonnieGurr you will need to set the height of the div the background image is in. It will probably be keeping the width because it is a block element and probably only 20px in height because that is the height of the inner content. If you want the image to take it's natural dimensions you should set it as an `img` element in the html

Comment: I did this but now when I try and put text on top of the background image it dose not show at all

Answer (score 1):

Background images and content images are not separate elements, they are styling of the element they're declared on.

For example, rather than using:

```
.news1 img:hover {
  /* ... */
}
```

You would use:

```
.news1:hover {
  /* ... */
}
```

If you actually want to style the image separately from the element, the image will have to have it's own element. This could be in the form of an inner `img` element, or by placing the image as the background of some other inner element.